# C# mixed use of Task and Dispatcher.Invoke, why it halts?

Tags: wpf, task, dispatcher

I tried below snippet:

```
    public Task RunUiTask(Action action)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, action);
        });
        return task;
    }

    private void OnCreateTask(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var task = RunUiTask(() =>
            {
                for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
                {
                    ResultTextBlock.Text += i.ToString();
                }
            });
        task.Wait();                        //(a) Program stopped here
        ResultTextBlock.Text += "Finished"; //(b) Never called;
    }
```

I couldn't understand why, when OnCreateTask (a button click event handler) is called,  the program halts at (a), and (b) is never called.

Note: I know I can use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to make program responsive, but this is not my concern here.

Can any body tell why the program halts at (a), and why (b) is never called? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The call of

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, action);
```

will execute `Action` in your UI Thread and will return after `Action` is executed.
The Problem is, that your UI Thead is blocked because of the `task.Wait()` in your `OnCreateTask`, so the Action will never be executed and you have a Deadlock.

**EDIT**

Instead of your `task.Wait()` you should use a Continuation and Update `ResultTextBlock.Text`

```
task.ContinueWith(t=>{
     ResultTextBlock.Text += "Finished";
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: How to solve the problem then? I don't want to use BeginInvoke

Comment: Run the OnCreateTask method contents in another thread then make sure that as you update the text block that you switch to the UI thread again.